# Uber Request Full Access - Still pending from last 3 weeks

Tags: oauth-2.0, connection, verification, uber-api, ubercart

We implemented and Tested the uber in  pricyfy App and we requested full Access to provide uber services to users 3 weeks ago.
Still Full Access is in pending state. We provided all required screenshots, Docs, videos, Flowchart...e.t.c, while requesting full access in developers dashboard .
May i know why this process is taking so much time. And Please help us how we can contact uber Team to enquire more about this.

Comment: @prakask421, Hi, I have similar issue and I don't see "request full access" button, do they solve your problem?Could you do the integration?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question appropriate for StackOverflow. For something that is not a technical / coding question but rather specific to Uber, you could reach out via appropriate channels such as https://twitter.com/UberDevelopers/ or on the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/uber-developers

In terms of your specific question, I know that there were replies to the email associated with that Pricyfy app specifying that access approval was denied as the app is breaking the Uber API terms. Hope that helps clear up your question.